# Laptop screen randomly flickers since Windows 8 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, intel-core-i5

Ever since installing Windows 8 I have been getting random screen flickering. I've tried to update the drivers without success. All the drivers for the intel HD 3000 I find on the Intel site say my system does not meet the minimum requirements. I am guessing my i5 430m must be a 1st gen. The only driver updates I can see are for 2nd and 3rd gen.

I have an Advent Sienna 510, Intel Core i5 430m with HD 3000 graphics

DirectX Diagnostic Tool Results:

[image: DirectX Diagnostic Tool Results]

Comment: can you characterize the flickering in any way? Brightness changes, blanks out, screen image distorts etc etc. Does it correlate even loosely with user interaction or specific states (context switching, program loading etc)?

Comment: It seems to be quite random but it happens at least once a day a while. It is like a blink, a single flicker once every few seconds. It happened again just now a seemed worse on a site that was very blue blue. I've also noticed it starts when opening apps with a transparent background but not always. It is a bit random to pin on anything. I've tried closing all apps I have open. If I put my computer to sleep for a bit it is completely fine again.

Comment: The first generation on-chip graphics pre-Sandy Bridge is what you have. Not 2nd or 3rd gen. So you are right to say it is "first gen" -- first gen integrated into the CPU. It's DirectX 10 class GPU but WDDM 1.1 driver is supported. This is likely a bug, not related to driver version/installation problem.

Comment: When you say DirectX 10 class will it cause issues to run DirectX 11  like I am? Also what would be the source of the bug?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. I tried everything, but nothing works. It turns out that it was a simple solution. The shielding of the cable was not enough. Maybe you first try to just change your cable to a better shielded one.

Comment: I think i've found the solution (see answer). It was setting based rather than hardware based.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be it only stops flickering if I set maximum brightness on the screen. Anything less and it flickers.

I am still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue on an EliteBook 8440p with Windows 8 installed. Random bright flickers only when running on battery.  Changing to Maximum Performance solves this issue.